# How to generate HTML with javascript on the server side (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, template-engine

I am trying to validate the user input from a register form, basically one of those forms when you create an account (signup), since after some research, people recommend to validate on both client side and server side to improve security.

**Objective**:
What I would like to achieve is when the user submits the form, therefore making a `POST` request to my server (the url can be /users/signup), the input will be validated with the use of express-validator. This way I can verify if the user specified a valid email, if the password and its confirmation match, etc, and if there are errors, I want to update the html page by adding a list of errors.

**Note** that I'd prefer to only update the necessary parts instead of the whole page to remove redundant rendering.

Now I know that I can use a template engine like `Jade` or `Handlebars`, which would result in code similar to this: `res.render('signup', {errors: errors.array()});` where errors is a variable containing the validation result, and then the signup file with the code of the particular templating engine. But I would like to know if there are other ways of achieving the same without learning a new template engine, maybe similar to what `JSX` code looks like.

Here is the code I propose that uses a module with the necessary implementation (its not completed):

```
let express = require("express");
const html = require("../htmlGenerator/html");  
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");

let router = express.Router();

/* Create a new account/user. */
router.post("/signup", [
    // Input Validation.
    check("email", "Email is not valid").isEmail()
    // ...
 ], (req, res) => {
     const errors = validationResult(req);

     if (!errors.isEmpty()) 
         res.send(htmlErrorList(errors.array()));

     //...
});

function htmlErrorList(errors) {
    return html.ul(
        errors.reduce((res, error) =>
            res + html.li({class: "alert alert-danger"}, error.msg), "")
    );
}
```

The idea of these functions, ul() and li(), is to create the HTML string with the given attributes (represented by an object with the properties being the attribute name and then its according value) and the content inside the tag we are creating.
The benefits I see with making or using a module that allows this sort of use are:

- It promotes functional style coding
- We don't need to learn a new template language to achieve something we can do with javascript
- We can use the full power and capabilities of the javascript language, for example make a function that produces the HTML code of the navbar used in all end-points of the app.

**Final notes**:
I know that many times we want to access a database or any other data source, on the server, and pull some data to make complex computations in order to format it and display in a way the user understands. One of the solutions is, again the use of a template engine, and I'd like to know if the idea I suggest is valid and if there are any other solutions to this problem.

I appreciate any help or feedback on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of "opinion" based so i will give my opinion.

1) Use a templating engine. It makes your life a lot easier.

2) Templating engines are easy to use. You can learn to use most them in half an hour. Making your own code would require a lot more time than just using an already proven method. Plus, other developers can easily read and edit the code if it's written using common tools whereas they would have to spend the time to learn whatever custom solution you have come up with.

3) Your example is so simple that you could generate that "HTML" just by concatenating strings and using template literals. If your example gets more complicated...than your solution would become much ... much harder to read and maintain.

4) You don't really need to "output" HTML for errors at all. Just output a JSON object and have the frontend handle it. e.g

*res.send({errors: [{field: 'username', message: 'username is required'}, ...]});*

5) You don't really need to output HTML for anything...other than the first page of your app/site. Keywords here are webpack + angular 2(angular is the "A" in MEAN stack).

It is used for a reason...it works and its good.

So, in summary, I would say, unless you have a really good reason to avoid template engines, I would go with a template engine.

Comment: "4) You don't really need to "output" HTML for errors at all. Just output a JSON object and have the frontend handle it. e.g". Could you tell me how would the server side code look like. Currently I don't know how to receive the response given by the server on the client side.

Comment: the example i gave you ... res.send() is how server sends a json to the client.
and the client receives it as a parameter for success/promise callback.
You can use jquery to make ajax requests. For example:
$.post('/signup', {username: 'John', password: '123'}).then((response) => {
    // here, response.errors would be the object your server sent.
});